# How can I get the source code of this strangely-behaving webpage?

Tags: youtube, url, microsoft-edge-devtools

Found some strange behavior, observed in both Firefox and Edge. The behavior does not change after closing all browser windows, restarting Firefox, and clearing all "YouTube" cookies.

In a [page with a list of YouTube channels](https://www.youtube.com/@galinhapintadinha/channels), I'm able to open all the channel pages in a new window and view the source code, except one. The eighth channel in the list, "Gallina Puntolina" is linked to

- https://www.youtube.com/@GallinaPuntolina

If I click on it in the channel list, I get the page, but if I ask to open it in a new window (or if I click on that link on this page), I get a window in which the address bar shows:

- https://www.youtube.com/gallinapuntolina

where the URL has been changed to all lower case and the "@" has been removed. The page is a "not found" error page, which is correct because this is an invalid YouTube URL.

If I then go back to the list page and just click, so the desired page comes up, but then I ask for the source code, I get a tab in which the address bar shows:

- [view-source:https://www.youtube.com/gallinapuntolina](https://view-source:https://www.youtube.com/gallinapuntolina)

and the HTML is the code for a "not found" error page, which is again correct because the URL has changed to an invalid YouTube URL.

Finally, if I go back to the desired page and copy the URL (the one above with "@" in it) and then open a new window and paste that in the address bar, when I press Enter, the URL changes to the invalid one in lower case without the "@" and the page is the "not found" error page. Same thing if I paste the URL:

- [view-source:https://www.youtube.com/@GallinaPuntolina](https://view-source:https://www.youtube.com/@GallinaPuntolina)

in the address bar. When I press Enter, the URL converts to the one in lower case without the "@".

**Summary:** I'm able to view the page by clicking the link for it in the channel list. But I'm not able to get the page in any other way, and I'm not able to view its source code. What do I need to do to get the source code of the page?

**Why I care:** I need the source code to get the channel's ID. In a YouTube page's source code, the channel ID is the value given for `externalId`. So, if I can't get the source code for the page, I need a different way to get the channel ID for that channel.

---

**Edit re DevTools**

When I originally posted the question, I had tried DevTools and didn't find anything useful, so I didn't mention it. But in a comment on his answer, @harrymc said to get the source code from DevTools, so I went back to that and found something even more strange. The following behavior has been observed in both Firefox and Edge.

In DevTools > Inspector, I went to the `html` tag, right-clicked and selected "Expand All" (in Edge, "Expand recursively"), then right-clicked again and selected "Copy > Outer HTML". I then pasted the clipboard into a new text file and saved it with extension "htm". I then opened that file.

At first, it appeared that what loaded was the channel list page, indicating that somehow the source code downloaded by DevTools was the code of the page that had linked to this page, not the page itself. But when I happened to open the file again, I noticed that the browser first came up with the correct page, and then after a second, that disappeared and was replaced with the channel list page. When I refreshed the page, sometimes I would see the correct page for a fraction of a second before it changed to the channel list, but sometimes I would only see the channel list.

I thought that perhaps this meant that either (a) the source code downloaded from DevTools was the correct source of the page with some sort of trigger that caused it to quickly access the channel list page and replace itself with that, or (b) the file somehow had source code for both pages. But I did a search for `externalId` in the file, and it is there only one time, followed by the channel ID of the parent channel (the channel of the channel list page), which indicates that if the file contains some part of the source code of the correct page, it does not contain the complete source of that page because the complete source should include the `externalId` of the channel. As explained above under *Why I care*, that is the whole reason I'm trying to get the source code of the page.

I hope @harrymc and maybe some other knowledgeable people will reproduce the behavior described here and explain what's going on.

Comment: Sounds like maybe youtube has an error in the coding (perhaps not listing the @) in the link... URL. Is that your page? You start up in the channels address for this @user. Have you tried saving the page from the beginning /channels ? Or start from the beginning and download the file instead of loading it in the browser. - Just a thought.

Comment: @vssher - I should have tried that, but it didn't help anyway. First, in the list page, I right-clicked and selected `Save link as`, and got the "not found" page. Then I left-clicked to load the page and saved it as HTML. It did save a page file, but it wasn't the page shown in the browser, but was the list page! So, the browser showed the page I wanted, but when I saved it to a file, I got the page file for the page that had loaded it. Very frustrating. How can a page be visible in the browser, but the code behind it not be accessible? (This is correction to previous comment, now deleted.)

Answer (score 1):

This page is tricky.
If you try to address this element by right-click and copy
its address you will get
`https://www.youtube.com/@GallinaPuntolina`,
but trying to use this as an URL will not work.
This is why you can't use this URL out of context.

If you trace the execution of the page, using for example
Fiddler, you will see a very different request being issued
by the JavaScript that is embedded in the page.

The main request looks like:
`https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/browse?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8&prettyPrint=false`.

However, this request cannot work by itself without the
data payload that is attached to that request.

In short, the link address that you get for the item is
misleading. The real request is issued by the YouTube page
and is not something that you can construct yourself
without diving into the JavaScript code.

This complexity was probably not done on purpose, just done
by a developer without much thinking.

Comment: Thanks for investigating this. If I understand correctly, you're saying that it was caused by an error in the coding of that page. Two questions: (1) Given all that, is there a way for me to view the source code of the page? (2) If not, why don't secretive websites reproduce that error in order to hide their source code?

Comment: Probably not an error, but intentional. (1) Use the Developer Tools of your browser.

Comment: Please see the new section added to the question, "Edit re DevTools", to see the strange behavior when I used DevTools to attempt to download the source,

Comment: The HTML is not enough - you also need the JavaScript and CSS files, and the page will not work the same from your disk as from the internet without some adjustments.

Comment: You told me to use DevTools, and I used that to get the HTML, although it turned out to not be the correct HTML of the page. Is there something else I should do in DevTools? I don't care about running the page on my computer, I just need the source HTML because it contains the `externalId`. This page has this very strange behavior that I can see the page if I get to it via the link on the channel list page, but I can't get its source code, including by using DevTools. I've changed the title of the question to emphasize that what I need is the source code. How can I get that?

Comment: I didn't mention DevTools in my answer. You may get the HTML of any page by doing "Save As" of the page in `.html` format. As I remarked, this may be incomplete and some data may only exist in other files or on the web server.

Comment: It was in a comment above that you told me to use DevTools to get the source code. Regarding "Save As", did you try that on the page at issue and did you get anything related to the page shown in the browser? As I said in my comment replying to the comment by @vssher on the question, when I tried "Save As" on the page or "Save Link As" on the list page, I either got the source code for a "Not Found" error page or the source code for the list page. Not incomplete source code of the page, but no source code at all related to the page.

Comment: I said that this page uses JavaScript heavily, which is why it is so hard to trace. However, once everything is displayed DevTools should show the HTML as-is. This page is tricky, so you have to know what to get.

Comment: Could you update your answer to say how to know what to get, and how to get everything displayed so DevTools will show the HTML for the page? Or at least a reference to where to find an explanation of those things?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431650/is-there-any-way-to-output-the-html-from-google-chrome-developer-tools) help?

Comment: That is the same process that I described in the part of my question, "Edit re DevTools", to get the HTML, which turned out to not be the correct HTML. When I wrote in a comment that I had done that, you responded, "The HTML is not enough ..." If you know how to do what is enough, it would be nice if you would say what it is,

Comment: What is enough would be to get all the files that are included in this HTML page. You may try to save the page in `.mhtml` format which includes everything, which can most times work as the page, but getting then at the individual files that were included is non-trivial.

Comment: I don't know about `.mhtml`, but in FireFox, I now saved as "Web page, complete", which gave me an htm file and a folder, "Gallina Puntolina - YouTube_files", which has 34 image, css, js, and other files. I ran the htm file and it gave me the same behavior described from the saved htm before. Then I searched for `externalId` in the htm and the folder. In the htm, it has the value of channel ID of the linking page, as before. In the folder it appears nine times in two js files, all in contexts I don't understand.

Comment: I guess the bottom line of your answer is: It's too complicated; forget it.

Comment: Your page is pulling HTML fragments from the server using [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) and incorporating them into the HTML. This is a very useful technique, but it prevents you from ever having the full page, and it also leads to complicated JavaScript routines. Yes, it's complicated and you must have some knowledge of HTML and JavaScript in order to decrypt it. It's a good incentive for studying the subject...

Comment: I have good knowledge of HTML and some JavaScript. Please suggest a resource for learning what I need to know to get enough of the HTML of that page to find the `externalId ` in it.

Comment: Search for tutorials about HTML and JavaScript, there are many. The above link is a good start, and from then on Google is your friend. Getting a book about the subject would also help.